# as far as what we can do better

Tags: phrase-meaning

Here's what a basketball player said on TV:

> We beat this team many times, but I feel like we haven't beat them in
> the right way **as far as what we can do better**.

What does "as far as what we can do better" mean here? (I know what "as far as" and "what we can do better" mean independently)Thanks!

Comment: This is an informal comment in very ungrammatical English. Don't use it as an example to copy! He seems to have meant something like "We haven't _beaten_ them in the right way, _insofar as_ we could have done it better".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The basketball player was speaking ungrammatically.

When speaking informally, without a prepared speech, sometimes speakers of English can make mistakes. In cases like this, it is likely the result of the speaker coming up with new ideas about what they wanted to say part of the way through the sentence and things getting jumbled together. I believe that the basketball player is noting that his team holds certain advantages over their opponent, but that those advantages haven't been properly utilized - even though his team won, they didn't win as a result of properly utilizing their advantages.

However, the phrase "as far as what we can do better" is a grammatically correct phrase, if not in the context of what the basketball player was saying. For instance, you could imagine a businessman talking to his team in a meeting, discussing mistakes that their team made, saying something like "Now, as far as what we could do better, I think we could improve our flow control processes by refactoring how we handle user stories." In this case, the phrase "as far as what we can do better" is essentially a preface for noting a flaw in their practices, along with a suggestion for how they could improve them.